# Калькулятор на стеке для простых математических знаков

Tags: c++, стек

Здравствуйте,посоветуйте,пожалуйста. Выполняю калькулятор(польская система) на стеке (на односвязном списке).

У меня фиксированное число для ввода значений (3) ,подскажите , пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы я вводил `значения` до знака `=`,например. Самый просто способ это перед циклом для ввода , спрашивать сколько значений будет в моем примере. Если ли иной способ?

И последний вопрос, так как я использую (польскую систему счета) , я могу не использовать  `скобки`?

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    Stack s;

    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++){
        int n;
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> n;
        s.Push(n);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter symbol (space for exit):";
        int choice = getchar();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '+':
            s.Push(s.Pop() + s.Pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            s.Push(-s.Pop() + s.Pop());
            break;
        case '*':
            s.Push(s.Pop()*s.Pop());
            break;
        case '/':
            s.Push(s.Pop() / s.Pop());
        case '=':
            std::cout <<"Result: "<< s.Pop()<<std::endl;
            break;
        case ' ':
            exit(-1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Не уверен, что этот комментарий строго по теме, но может будет чем-то полезен. Есть классический пример, который гуглится по запросу "lex yacc calculator".

Comment: @AlexanderZonov  Гуглю.. Вы можете какие-нибудь поправки добавить?

Comment: Можно вводить строки. Например, `do{...} while(n!="=")`

Comment: скобки - операторы изменения приоритетов операций, в ОПЗ скобок нет.

Comment: @vp_arth Принял,спасибо. А на счет ввода чисел, как лучше определять сколько значений будет в выражение?

Comment: Я же написал - вводить числа строками до определённого маркера, в теле цикла строки приводить к числам.

Comment: @vp_arth Извините, спасибо за советы!

Comment: В реализации функций вычитания и деления ошибка. Порядок вызова .Pop() неопределенный. Советую сохранять результат во временные переменные.